# merge multiple data providers in single in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am working on Selenium with TestNG framework. I have multiple data providers and I want to merge them and send in Test. These are the data providers that I have created

```
@DataProvider(name = "Sample1")     
public Object[][] createData1() {           
Object[][] retObjArr= ExcelUtils.getTableArray  ("Test\\resources\\data\\Testdata.xls","test1", "selector1");      
 return(retObjArr);     }           

@DataProvider(name = "Sample2")     
public Object[][] createData2() {           
Object[][] retObjArr= ExcelUtils.getTableArray ("Test\\resources\\data\\Testdata.xls","test2", "selector2");            return(retObjArr);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have single method called createData and you can pass Method as argument to it and that should tell you for which test method which data to be fetched from which file. Maintain mapping of test method to Test data file somewhere. Let me know if this helps.
Sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] dp(Method method)
    {
        if(method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test1"))
            return new Object[][]{{"dp1"}};
        else if(method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test2"))
            return new Object[][]{{"dp2"}};
        else
            return new Object[][]{{"default"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="dp")
    public void test1(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="dp")
    public void test2(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }


}
```

Output:

```
dp1
dp2
PASSED: test1("dp1")
PASSED: test2("dp2")

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

EDIT: Added sample code.

Comment: Hi Mrunal.. thanks for the reply.. could you please explain it with example.

Comment: @ShwetaKhandewalePathak i've added a sample working code. pls go through it and let me know if this helps.

Comment: @halfer may i know what needs to be fixed in this comments?

Comment: sorry..i'll make a note of it from next time..edited post with proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

Mrunal is talking about something like this,

```
 @DataProvider(name="getDataFromFile")
public static Iterator<Object[]> getDataFromFile(Method testMethod) throws Exception
{   
    String expected=null;
    String webServicename=testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
    Reporter.log("Providing data for web service " + webServicename,true);
    // Read from a map what all data you should send from what what xls files
// create the dataset here

//send the test data to the test method
}
```

Your test method should look like this

```
@Test(dataProvider="getDataFromFile",dataProviderClass=utility.TestDataController.class)
    public void runTest(<whateverdataprovider returns in a row> data) throws Exception {
// use data
}
```

So essentially you send the data from both the files but from a single data provider.